Configuring SELinux labels for selective container access using Podman and MCS
podman use Multi-Category Security (MCS) to make sure only certain container can access the path.
for example, if I do -v /host/test:/container/test:Z it will change the label of /host/test to system_u:object_r:container_file_t:s0:c106,c548
The c106,c548 is corresponding to current container process. This flag persists.
However, if the user do not have permission to change /host then he cannot use :Z to modify the label.
My question is, as a sysop how can I correctly pre-config the selinux labels for /host/test to make sure it is accessible by some containers? What is the canonical way to do this?
I don't know if one can force the process into special category. If not, then what is the proper way to define the label to allow only some containers to access the path?

According to RedHat documentation:

MCS works on a simple principle: to access a file, a user must be assigned to all of the categories that have been assigned to the file.

So if a file have no category, it can be accessed by your containers as long as it is labeled as container_file_t.
So you can do:
semanage fcontext -a -t container_file_t '/host/test'
restorecon -F /host/test

Then mount without the Z flag.
Although, it will be accessible by all containers.
If you want it to be accessible only by one specific context, you would need to explicitly set it with semanage or define the container contexts with podman (no idea if this is possible).
